# realmswift how to filter Results using bitwise operator

Tags: realm

I have a mail realm object, I want to filter mails  which the ((flags & 8) == 0)
the mail object is define like this:

```
class Mail: Object {
    @objc dynamic var mailID = ""
    @objc dynamic var imapUid: Int64 = 0
    @objc dynamic var flags = 0
}
```

I use this, Not work

```
Ream().objects(Mail.self).filter("flags & 8) = 0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm doesn't support bitwise predicates. A list of all supported predicates can be found [on our NSPredicate cheatsheet](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/); supported predicates are marked by a pink dot.

If you need to be able to perform queries, use boolean variables instead of or in addition to the bitwise flag.